# Meteor re-render template after a button is clicked

Tags: templates, meteor, dynamic, meteor-blaze, rerender

I am working a webpage which will show the search result. After the "search" button was clicked, a search_array should be passed into the template dynamically. How could I dynamically refresh the template after clicking the button?
Here is my code:

search_post.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">search by name</label>
  <div class="controls">
      <input name="SearchName" id="SearchName" type="text" value="" placeholder="enter the name" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />

<div id="info" style="display: block; margin-top: 5%">
   {{#if show}}
   {{#each getInfo}}
      {{> postItem}}
   {{/each}}
   {{/if}}
</div>
```

search_post.js

```js
var search_array;
Template.postSearch.events({
  'click .btn': function() {   
     search_array = Posts.find({person_name: document.getElementsByName('SearchName')[0].value});
     Session.set('show', true);
  }
});

Template.postSearch.helpers({
  getInfo: function() {
     return search_array
  },

  show: function(){
        return Session.get('show');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Session` variable or `ReactiveVar` instead of a normal variable `search_array`. That way when you change it the template will automatically update.

```
Template.postSearch.events({
    'click .btn': function () {
        let searchName = document.getElementsByName('SearchName')[0].value;
        Session.set('searchArray', Posts.find({person_name: searchName}).fetch());
        Session.set('show', true);
    }
});

Template.postSearch.helpers({
    getInfo() {
        return Session.get('searchArray');
    }
});
```

You could also just store `searchName` in the `Session`/`ReactiveVar` and do the database query in `getInfo`, that way the template will automatically rerender if the database changes.